# Boot into Plasma again

Tags: kubuntu, kde, startup, plasma, kodi

I configured an Auto Login and a session login into kodi in my system.
It is running Kubuntu 18.04 with plasma desktop.
To achieve that I used /System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen > Advanced Tab (Configure Login Manager) and marked >Auto Login< the user and >Kodi< instead of >Plasma< under session. I marked >Relogin after quit< either. See here:

[Configure Login Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTCXV.png)

After reboot, the system starts kodi now, but it is not possible to boot into plasma again. Kodi offers no choice for that. When I leave kodi with exit or reboot, the system boots into kodi again. 
I have ssh access but don´t know what to change to boot into plasma again.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards and Thanks in advance for any help
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve had the exact same issue. I found another easier way. Simply go to the lower left corner of your home screen while in Kodi, and click on the “Power Off” icon.  This brings up a few options one of which is “Exit”.   Click “Exit”.  The Kodi app will eventually close itself.  Be patient!  For me it took 3-4 minutes and appeared that the system was hung. But it in fact was just shutting down Kodi behind the scenes.  Once it eventually closes you will be presented woth the Plasma Login screen. Don’t login!!  You have to look in the extreme lower left corner of your computer screen and you SHOULD see a little drop down icon that if you click it it will let you select which desktop to log in to. Kodi or Plasma.  I now use this all the time.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

OK, it is askUbuntu, but I will answer myself. I found out how to fix the issue:
The file 
/etc/sddm.conf
contains the following:

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=true
Session=kodi.desktop
User=MYNAME

[General]
HaltCommand=
RebootCommand=

[Theme]
Current=breeze
CursorTheme=breeze_cursors

[Users]
MaximumUid=65000
MinimumUid=1000
```

To switch again to normal desktop environment you have to change to

```
 [Autologin]
    Relogin=false
    Session=plasma.desktop
    User=
```

...

Perhaps someone has the same problem and can use this as a solution.
Regards